# Conjugating kommen in Präteritum/preterite

Tags: preterite

In this [article](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/de/deutsch-grammatik-lernen/the-imperfect-tense#:%7E:text=The%20imperfect%20tense%20is%20generally,%2C%20%2Dtet%2C%20%2Dten.), the praeteritum construction with adding -te ending is explained (and also the exceptions). It seems to me these rules don't explain who kommen is conjugated in praeteritum as shown [here](https://www.die-konjugation.de/verb/kommen.php)

[image]

By what systematic rules were kommen conjugated in the above table and where can I read more about it?

Comment: Look for "starke verben", e.g. https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Tabelle_starker_Verben. "schwach" means regular conjugation, "stark" irregular conjugaton with changing vowels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table you reproduced has a strange coloring, it would be easier to recognize, if *kam* were black everywhere and just the variable ending in red.

The summary of the rules taken from [here](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/verbformen/die-konjugation-praeteritum/die-konjugation-praeteritum-uebersicht/) are:

> - Beim Präteritum der unregelmäßigen Verben bekommen die 1. und 3. Person Singular keine Personenendung.
> - Die Personenendungen in der 2. Person Singular und im Plural entsprechen den Personenendungen im Präsens.

Translated:

- For irregular verbs in preterite the forms for first and third person singular receive no ending.
- Second person singular as well as plural have same endings as in present tense.

Apart from the second bullet this explanation was already given on the collins grammar page you started with in section 3.

Comment: Just a nitpick, but there are a few weak verbs which are also irregular. Some, for example *brennen*, have a vowel change and weak endings in the past tense, so *ich brannte*, not *ich brann*. Others, for example *bringen*, have more complex changes but still have weak endings, so *ich brachte*, not *ich brach*. Then there are preterite present verbs, which includes all modal verbs. In the present tense they look like a strong verb in the past tense and in the past tense they look like weak verbs in the past tense. This may depend on how you define "irregular* vs. "regular".

Answer (score 1):

As Carsten S mentioned, the Collins article you linked has separate sections (2 and 3) for Weak and Strong verbs, and *kommen* is a strong verb so you were looking at the wrong table. I don't think there's a way of telling which verbs are weak vs. strong, though the more commonly used verbs, such as *kommen*, are often strong.

The article also has a section for Mixed, which seems to be a leftovers bin for verbs that don't fit neatly into the Strong or Weak categories. I'm not convinced that's a useful category, at least the way Collins seems to be defining it. German verb conjugation is challenging, but certain patterns emerge even for irregular verbs, and the more patterns you can find the less you have to memorize.

Answer (score 0):

Your question links to an article and references information from the section “Forming the imperfect tense of weak verbs”. The information that you ask for can be found in the section “Forming the imperfect tense of strong verbs”.